# Search query for elasticsearch when child element is array of string

Tags: elasticsearch

I created a documents in elasticsearch in the following format

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_base.main_candidate/" -d'
{
    "specific_location": {
        "location_name": "Mumbai",
        "location_tags": [
            "Mumbai"
        ],
        "tags": [
            "Mumbai"
        ]
    }
}'
```

My requirement is to search for location_tags containing one of the given options like ["Mumbai", "Pune"]. How do I do this?

I tried:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/my_base.main_candidate/_search" -d '
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "specific_location.location_tags" : ["Mumbai"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

which didn't work.

I got this output :

```
{
  "took": 72,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a several ways to solve this. Perhaps the most immediate one is to search for `mumbai` instead of `Mumbai`.

If I create the index with no mapping,

```
curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/my_base.main_candidate/"
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_base.main_candidate/"
```

then add a doc:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_base.main_candidate/doc/1" -d'
{
   "specific_location": {
      "location_name": "Mumbai",
      "location_tags": [
         "Mumbai"
      ],
      "tags": [
         "Mumbai"
      ]
   }
}'
```

then run your query with the lower-case term

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/my_base.main_candidate/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "terms": {
               "specific_location.location_tags": [
                  "mumbai"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

I get back the expected doc:

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "my_base.main_candidate",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "specific_location": {
                  "location_name": "Mumbai",
                  "location_tags": [
                     "Mumbai"
                  ],
                  "tags": [
                     "Mumbai"
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

This is because, since no explicit mapping was used, Elasticsearch uses defaults, which means the `location_tags` field will be analyzed with the [standard analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html), which will convert terms to lower-case. So the term `Mumbai` does not exist, but `mumbai` does.

If you want to be able to use upper-case terms in your query, you will need to set up an explicit mapping that tells Elasticsearch not to analyze the `location_tags` field. Maybe something like this:

```
curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/my_base.main_candidate/"

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_base.main_candidate/" -d'
{
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "specific_location": {
               "properties": {
                  "location_tags": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "index": "not_analyzed"
                  },
                  "tags": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "index": "not_analyzed"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_base.main_candidate/doc/1" -d'
{
   "specific_location": {
      "location_name": "Mumbai",
      "location_tags": [
         "Mumbai"
      ],
      "tags": [
         "Mumbai"
      ]
   }
}'

curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/my_base.main_candidate/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "terms": {
               "specific_location.location_tags": [
                  "Mumbai"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

Here is all the above code in a handy place:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/74844f4d779f7c2b94a9ab65fd76eb0ffe294cbb

[EDIT: by the way, I used Elasticsearch `1.3.4` when testing the above code]